# Why does this Python logic update all keys in the dictionary

Tags: python

Please see Python example below:

```
data = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, [])
children = ["one", "two"]
for child in children:
    current_key = child[0].lower()
    data[current_key].append(child)

print("data: ", data)
```

Why does this update all keys with all values from the children list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why all keys are updated with all values from the children list is because the `fromkeys` method of the dict class creates a dictionary where all keys share the same reference to a single list object. Therefore, when you append values to one key's list, you're actually modifying the same list object that is referenced by all keys.

To fix this, you need to create a new list object for each key. You can do this by using a dictionary comprehension instead of the `fromkeys` method. Here's the corrected code:

```
import string

data = {key: [] for key in string.ascii_lowercase}
children = ["one", "two"]

for child in children:
    current_key = child[0].lower()
    data[current_key].append(child)

print("data: ", data)
```

Comment: Amazing - this worked thanks. Was really stuck on this one, why would I want to create a dict where all keys shared the same reference to a single list object?

Comment: Not really sure if there is any need for that, but that's just how it works.

Comment: @Dan Well why did you? You were the one who did that. Despite the function's documentation explicitly warning against that.